# QGIS form very basic formula not working

Tags: qgis, expression

I have a table with 6 columns (let´s name them A, B, C, D, E, F). The sum of them on each record must be 100.
The A column can be any value between 5 and 100.
The B column must be 100-A
The C column must be 100-A-B
And so on until the F column that is 100-A-B-C-D-E.
Simple as it is, when I enter any value in A, the other columns doesnt calculate correctly:

[image]

In the image, the columns are sorted from left to right (A, B, C, D, E, F).
The expression I use for column F is:

```
100-"Ponderacion_Ganadero_1"-"ponderacion_ganadero_2"-"ponderacion_ganadero_3"-"ponderacion_ganadero_4"-"ponderacion_ganadero_5"
```

The expression preview is correctly calculated, but in the table, as it can be seen, it is not.
I checked "Apply default value on update", as I want them all to update when I change one.

I tried changing the formula (100-(A+B+C+D+E)) or wrapping each field with `to_real` just in case.
Something that confuses me a lot is that I don't achieve the same results in C, D, E, F when I change A from 100 to another value. Only B is consistent. In the example above, A and B of the first 2 rows are the same (I just changed A to 90), but the others not.

Recently landed to using expressions in QGIS.

Comment: My guess is that the column are not calculated sequentially from A to F (I mean column D could be calculated before column C is) so it always work for B (as it only need column A) but other column can't get proper value....

Comment: From the description, wouldn't C,D,E,F always be 0?

Comment: I thought in the sequentially problem. That could be but... Why? And, if it's that, how to solve?

Comment: Regarding that C,D,E,F should be 0, yes, at least while only change the value of A. I have yet to think how to enter a value in B so C is recalculated and so on. In the end, I want to be able to have a row with, e.g. 50,20,10,10,5,5. Perhaps it's easier using constrains...

Comment: I think you are confusing the field editor with a spread sheet, it works in columns not sheets

Comment: And I´m working with columns, am I not?. I´m trying to calculate the value of one column based on the value of another column... but using six columns. How can I do it then?

Comment: I would advice you creating a model the first calculates the values for B, then for C, D etc. Define an action that calls the model when you change field A. Or try solving it using Python - in this case you should edit the question accordingly.